# .NET Core 2.1 Logging to database from a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to log to a database with items like the configuration sitting in the class library for .NET Core 2.1?

I managed to build a working version for .NET MVC 5 using NLog. However, when it came to .NET Core 2.1, there was a reliance in setting it as a service in Startup.cs and Program.cs.

I actually asked about it in another post but this one is just to get a recommendation for a guide or tutorial to see if its possible?

This is the other post where I showed my code and configuration with NLog
[ASP.NET Core 2.1 Using Nlog configuration as .NET MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584564/asp-net-core-2-1-using-nlog-configuration-as-net-mvc5)

Comment: That's because the MVC 5 logic is wrong as well. A controller shouldn't call a loger directly. Even in MVC 5 the logger should be provided as an abstract dependency, eg as an `ILog<>` interface parameter in the controller's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Especially within a class library, you should be using a logging fascade, like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, rather than a concrete logging provider such as NLog. You then simply inject the logging fascade into your class library classes like:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Foo(ILogger<Foo> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    ...
}
```

Inside the class, then, you use the injected logging instance set to the `_logger` ivar. Then, in your actual project that utilizes this class, you set you your logging provider and register the appropriate services. That way, each individual app controls it's own logging providers, and your class library classes just use the abstraction.

Comment: Sorry just want to clarify, does this mean that if my app is split into App.UI, App.Data, App.ClassLibrary and I want to log in App.UI, and App.Data I'll have to set up individual configurations(Connection Strings, etc) for each of the modules?

Comment: Also, what happens if App.Data does not have a Startup.cs or appsettings.json?

Comment: No. That's sort of the whole point. You set up your logging in the actual application that's running, i.e. `App.UI`, most likely. All your code just use the a logging fascade, which will be setup against an actual provider in your running application.

Comment: Ah I see. But if an exception happens on my data layer, will the UI layer know about it? Sorry, I'm very new to .net still.

Comment: Yes, essentially. There's only one running application. The other projects are simply dependencies. That means their code gets compile into the running application's code, much the same as if it existed in that project directly. Breaking it out into separate projects is for organization, they don't run independently.

Comment: How will the logger know that an exception is caught in App.Data if there isn't a log function there though?

Comment: There will be. Your class library uses the logging abstraction to log, i.e `ILogger` in the example code. Once that is injected, you can do stuff like `_logger.LogException(e, e.Message)` to log an exception in the your `catch`. Under the hood, this will end up calling the appropriate method(s) on the logging provider you've registered. The class library itself knows nothing of NLog, etc. It just knows if it wants to log an exception it calls `ILogger.LogException`. Your application is what defines what actually happens with that.

Comment: Instead of throwing an exception you could alternatively use `_logger = logger ?? NullLogger<Foo>.Instance;`

Comment: Yes. That's if you want the logging to be optional. The null logger does what it says on the tin: nothing. But, it satisfies the dependency. That can also be dangerous, though, because we developers can be a lazy bunch, and given the opportunity to not log, we probably won't. Throwing an exception forces you to think about it. It's a stylistic choice though.